# Unloading Snowflake table data into S3 in Parquet format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

i am trying to unload Snowflake tale data into S3 bucket in parquet format. but getting below error.

```
`SQL compilation error: COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import.`
```

below is the syntax of copy statement

```
`create or replace stage STG_LOAD
url='s3://bucket/foler'
credentials=(aws_key_id='xxxx',aws_secret_key='xxxx')
file_format = (type = PARQUET);

copy into STG_LOAD from
(select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(country_cd,source)
 from table_1 
file_format = (type='parquet')
header='true';`
```

please let me know if i am missing anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to identify named stages using the @ symbol. Also the header option is `true` rather than `'true'`

```
copy into @STG_LOAD from
(select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(country_cd,source)
 from table_1 )
file_format = (type='parquet')
header=true;
```

Comment: What's the error for header you're getting? Did you change from `'true'` to just `true` without the single quotes?

Comment: i have given true in single quotes, with out quotes it is working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, table is having Nulls after using correct syntax of copy statement. could you suggest whats wrong.
i have created one more new thread for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740053/unload-snowflake-table-data-into-s3-in-parquet-format