# Unload Snowflake table data into S3 in Parquet format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i could see all the values as Null's under the columns after loading into S3 bucket from Snowflake table.

below is the code i have used.

```
create or replace stage STG_LOAD
url='s3://bucket/foler'
credentials=(aws_key_id='xxxx',aws_secret_key='xxxx')
file_format = (type = PARQUET);

copy into STG_LOAD from
(select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(country_cd,source)
 from table_1 
file_format = (type='parquet')
header='true';
```

please let me know if i am missing something here.

Comment: so are you getting an error? what's the issue? by the way `snowflake_schema` is a data warehouse data model , which I think its unrelated to this question

Comment: no error i am getting, it is not snowflake schema, it is snowflake(cloud dw) table. it is related to snowflake cloud datawarehouse

Comment: COPY INTO should be under form *COPY INTO @STG_LOAD*

Comment: still null values are coming
`copy into @STG_LOAD from
(select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(country_cd,source)
 from table_1 
file_format = (type='parquet')
header=true;`

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to see null values. It's expected behaviour. Your SELECT produces an empty object, therefore it is written as NULL values:

```
create or replace table table_1 
( country_cd varchar, source varchar ) as
select * from values 
('US','Jack'),
('UK','Joe'),
('NL','Jim'),
('EU', null);

select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(country_cd,source) output
from table_1

+------------------+
|      OUTPUT      |
+------------------+
| { "US": "Jack" } |
| { "UK": "Joe" }  |
| { "NL": "Jim" }  |
| {}               |
+------------------+
```

If you don't want to write null values, you can filter them on your select:

```
copy into @STG_LOAD from
(select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(country_cd,source ) output
 from table_1 
where output != OBJECT_CONSTRUCT() ) -- no empty objects
file_format = (type=parquet)
overwrite = true;
```